# Mysql - Search by tokenized string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple request: search by a user name. 
Nevertheless, imagine I have this data on database:

```
1 - John Amazing Doe
2 - John Stupid Doe
3 - John Anthony
```

When I search by "John Doe", is there an easy way to search by results that have "john" or "doe"? Even better, if we could rank by who has more matches?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with a full text index.  Here is a place to start:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Prepare the data prior to building the query

This is something that would be best handled a bit programmatically prior to sending to MySQL.

Turn the name into a list, break on space:

- `"John Doe" --> "John|Doe"`
- SELECT username FROM users WHERE username RLIKE 'John|Doe'

Be careful about sql injection here.

## php Example

```
$db = new PDO([conn info]);

$searchArg = 'John Doe';
$nameRegex = str_replace(' ','|', strtolower($searchArg));

$userSearch = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE LOWER(username) REGEXP :nameRegex');
$userSearch->bindValue(':nameRegex', $nameRegex, PDO::PARAM::STR);
$userSearch->execute();

foreach ( $userSearch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $user ) {
    echo $user['username'] . '\n<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A full text index and `MATCH()` is your best option.  That said, here is another way:

You can search for names that have 'John' or 'Doe' using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT user_name
FROM   users
WHERE  user_name LIKE 'John%' 
OR     user_name LIKE '%Doe'
```

Use leading and trailing `%` only if names will not always start with 'John' or end with 'Doe', otherwise use one.  Double `%` will not make use of any indexes you have on `user_name`

You can then rank these using `UNION` and sorting column:

```
    SELECT user_name, 1 as Sort_Col
    FROM   users
    WHERE  user_name LIKE 'John%' 
    AND    user_name LIKE '%Doe'
UNION
    SELECT user_name, 2 as Sort_Col
    FROM   users
    WHERE (user_name LIKE 'John%' 
    OR     user_name LIKE '%Doe')
    AND    user_name NOT IN (
               SELECT user_name
               FROM   users
               WHERE  user_name LIKE 'John%' 
               AND    user_name LIKE '%Doe')
    ORDER BY Sort_Col ASC
```

You'll have to use an annoying `NOT IN` for the second query to be sure that you don't return rows that have both 'John' and 'Doe'.  Normally the `UNION` would suffice, but since we added `Sort_Col` it will not.  Just another reason to add a full text index if at all possible.